# PHP Amazon S3: "Class 'AmazonS3' not found". How to upload and download files from bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to get started with using the S3 buckets, I've tried all 3 of the methods documented here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html

but all I get is "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'AmazonS3' not found in..

What could be wrong?

```
<?php
    require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;

    // Instantiate the class
    $s3 = new AmazonS3();

    $response = $s3->get_bucket_list();

    // Success?
    print_r($response);
?>
```

I've gone also through numerous other questions from other people with no working solution so far.

Could I get some -full- working code with an example of uploading a file to a bucket and get a public link to the file to be downloadable?

Comment: Did you verify your path to auto-loader is correct and also documentation shows to create the client as `$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([...]);`

Comment: Ahh thank you, I got it working now, managed to upload a file and get the url. thanks!

Comment: tip: if you turn on PHP warnings and errors during development, it will tell you about problems like this along with undefined variables, missing array elements, PDO errors, ... just remember to turn it off again for production since it can give information to attackers.  `error_reporting(E_ERROR);  ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  -- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php